Is Mercédès pregnant with Edmond’s second child?
At the end of the 2002 movie, The Count of Monte Cristo, as Edmond, Mercédès, and Albert are walking off the island Chateau d’If, is Mercédès pregnant with Edmond's second child? It looks like she is.

Looks like it by the way she holds her stomach, but nothing is stated in the movie. The earlier 2000 script doesn't even have her make it to the end. Other scripts are paywalled AFAIK
